# While trying upload PDF files using Fineuploader. It through an unknow Error exception

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader to upload images and pdf files for my contact form. But when i try uploading pdf files, it cause an unknown error exception even if i add the pdf extention to the allowedExtensions array.
Images are uploaded without problems.

Here ist my config code:

```js
var DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
  autoUpload: true,
  cors: {
    expected: true,
  },
  maxConnections: 2,
  element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
  request: {
    endpoint: SERVICE_ENDPOINT,
    forceMultipart: false,
    params: SERVICE_PARAMS,
  },
  validation: {
    sizeLimit: 1024 * 1024 * 50,
    allowedExtensions:["bmp","gif","jpg","jpeg",
                       "pcx","png","tga","tiff", "tif", "doc", "docx", "pdf"],
  },
  workarounds: {
    iosEmptyVideos: false,
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: The error is "Upload failure reason unknown".

Comment: The issue is probably due to an issue with your server's response. Please post the console log messages according to your browser's developer tools as well as the response from your server to Fine Uploader's upload POST request according to your browser's developer tools network tab.

Comment: @ Ray: indeed it was a server config. that prevent adding my uploads to an other Service. thanks for your comment.